# Passport w/node.js Google error

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm attempting to use passport with an express/node.js app. For some reason I can't authenticate using google. Google gives the following error:

Error: invalid_request
Error in parsing the OpenID auth request.

```
Code:

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google').Strategy;
var UserModel = require('./models/usermodel');

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    returnURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/return',
    realm: 'http:/localhost:3000'
  },
  function(identifier, profile, done) {
    profile.email = profile.emails[0].value;
    UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({email:profile.email}, {$set:profile, $inc:{logins:1}}, {upsert:true}, done);
  }
));
```

Comment: Check this answer out , implementation details using oauth2 [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352975/passport-google-oauth-on-localhost

Answer (score 7):

If you don't otherwise have reason to use OpenID, I highly recommend switching to OAuth 2.0, which is implemented in [passport-google-oauth](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth).

Google seems to be recommending that as their preferred authentication solution, and their OpenID implementation seems to receive less attention and spurious errors occur.

Answer (score 0):

I know how late this is, but I thought it was worth noting that your realm is incorrect and that's probably why you got this error.  You only have one slash after the protocol -- `http:/local` instead of `https://local`.

Answer (score 0):

first things first. Make sure your gems are up to date. So add this to your package.json and then run npm install or npm update. I am 99% sure this is it since an old google gem broke mine.

```
{
  "name": "Boilerplate",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.1.0",
    "ejs": "*",
    "stylus": "*",
    "mongoose": "*",
    "connect-mongo": "*",
    "passport": "*",
    "passport-google": "*",
    "passport-twitter": "*",
    "passport-facebook": "*",
    "passport-local": "*"
  }
}
```

Then Run:

```
npm install
```

Here is what I have for the passport info on my server.js

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id)
})

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  UserModel.findOne({ _id: id }, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user)
  })
})

var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google').Strategy;
var UserModel = require('./models/usermodel'); // A schema that is not optional 

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    returnURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/return',
    realm: 'http://localhost:3000'
  },
  function(identifier, profile, done) {
    console.log(profile);
      UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({email:profile.email}, {$set:profile, $inc:{logins:1}}, {upsert:true}, done);
  }
));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems returnURL doesn't play nicely when a port number is included in it.
This means you may need to switch to the standard port (80), which on some linux flavours won't work unless you tweaked the OS to allow non-root users access to that port. I'd consider OAuth 2.0 though, as suggested above, before diving in.