# passport google oauth on localhost

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I am quite new at using passport for authentication over node, hence the lot of code snippets

my server is configured as :

```
var router = require('./app/config/routes');
var googleStrategy = require('./app/config/passport');
var session = require("express-session");

var passport = require('passport');
app.use(session({secret : '<secret-key>'}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
googleStrategy(passport);
```

my routes are configured as

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {

    app.get('/auth/google', function() {
        passport.authenticate('google', {scope: ['profile', 'email']});
    });

    app.get('/auth/google/callback', function() {
        passport.authenticate('google', {
            successRedirect: '/profile',
            failureRedirect: '/fail'
        });
    });

    .... ALSO configured /profile and /fail
};
```

my passport is configured as

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, callback){
        console.log('serializing user.');
        callback(null, user);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(user, callback){
       console.log('deserialize user.');
       callback(null, user);
    });

    var processRequest = function(token, refreshToken, profile, callback){
        process.nextTick(function(){
           console.log('id : '+ profile.id);
           console.log('name :'+ profile.displayName);
           console.log('email :' + profile.emails);
           console.log('token : '+ token);
        });
    };

    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: 'client ID',
        clientSecret : 'client SECRET',
        callbackURL : 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/google/callback',
        realm : 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'
    }, processRequest));
```

Problem : on going to `/auth/google` , I never get a confirmation screen. What should be I looking at?

### Update :

changing the routes to the configuration shown below made it work.

```
    app.get('/auth/google', 
        passport.authenticate('google', {scope: ['profile', 'email']})
    );

    app.get('/auth/google/callback', 
        passport.authenticate('google', {
            successRedirect: '/profile',
            failureRedirect: '/fail'
        })
    );
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Currently OAUTH2 protocol for authentication and autherization is well supported by google.So Its better to use the same . [Here is](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) google's documentation on it .Use **'passport-google-oauth'** module . Here is the implementation.This should be the app objects configuration , also see that oauth2strategy object is used from passport-google-oauth module , also check out the scopes in the app.get route registration .

```
var googleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
  app.configure(function() {

    app.set('views',  './views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.session({secret:'MySecret'}));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static('./public'));
});

app.get('/auth/google', select.passport.authenticate('google',{scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.google.com/m8/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'}));

app.get('/auth/google/callback', function() {
    passport.authenticate('google', {
        successRedirect: '/profile',
        failureRedirect: '/fail'
    });
});
app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
        req.logOut();
        res.redirect('/');
    });
```

But before creating a new strategy go to googles developer console and get clientID and secret . Here are the steps

1. go this [link](https://console.developers.google.com/project) and create project , here is the snapshot of the same [image]
2. give a new project name and ID , here is the snapshot [image]
3. It'll roughly take a minute to create your new project , once your new project is created it'll redirect you to the application configuration of your app . In the redirected page select **APIS AND AUTH** -> **API's** , In the API's page enable the GOogle+ API , here is the snapshot of it [image]
4. then go to credentials(below APIs), then click on **Create New Client Id** , and register the domains and callback for your app(configure the domain to be localhost ) , here is its snapshot ![image]
   5.Then u'll get your new ID and secret . Use them to create the new Strategy

   ```
   passport.use(new googleStrategy({
       clientID: '<TheNewclientID>',
       clientSecret: '<The New Secret>',

       callbackURL: "http://locahost:8080/auth/google/callback"
   },
   function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
       console.log(profile); //profile contains all the personal data returned 
       done(null, profile)
   }
   ));
   ```

6.now serialize and deserialize

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, callback){
        console.log('serializing user.');
        callback(null, user.id);
    });

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, callback){
       console.log('deserialize user.');
       callback(null, user.id);
    });
```

run the server and go to localhost:8080/auth/google (dont use 127.0.0.1:8080 instead of locahost ) .This should be getting it working :)

[Other useful links: 
Check out the first comment by kvcrawford on the repo of the module in [this](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth/issues/4) page
Passport-google is another popular module which is use to provide login using google , its kind of outdated now , here is the [link](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google/issues/25) with respect to its recent issues ]

Comment: thanks for the elaborate answer. I solved my issue, which was in setting up the routes as shown in the update. But it was good to verify everything from a second source :)

Comment: Important to note that 'www' has to be removed while using 'localhost' as the domain, like so: 'http://localhost:3000'

Comment: It looks like google does not allow localhost urls for the redirect: "Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Non-public domains not allowed: http://locahost:4000/auth/google/callback"

Comment: @Mnebuerquo it worked for me with `http://127.0.0.1/auth/google/callback` where you missing the `http://` ?

Answer (score 8):

In most examples on the web, routing code is done like this:

```
app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google'));
```

According to the [Express Reference](http://expressjs.com/api.html), callbacks of the `app.get` method are given three arguments, `request`, `response` and 'next'. That means, the authenticate method in the above example returns a function object and it is executed with three the arguments `request`, `response` and 'next'.

So, if you would like do authentication in the callback function of the `app.get` method like this:

```
app.get('/auth/google', function() {
    passport.authenticate('google', {scope: ['profile', 'email']});
});
```

then you should write:

```
app.get('/auth/google', function(request, response, next) {
    passport.authenticate('google', {scope: ['profile', 'email']})(request, response, next);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you @Seiya but I would add a redirect

```
app.get(
    "/auth/google/callback", 
    passport.authenticate('google'),
    (req, res) => {
      res.redirect('/whatever')
    }
);
```