# Missing scope error on Google authentication callback using Node.js/Passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, passport.js

This error occurs on Heroku (production) only, not on local.
I have tried both:

```
passport.authenticate('google', { scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly' })
```

And,

`passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] })`

Whether the scope is an array, or a space-delimited string.

When I go to the Google authentication link, scope IS in the URL. There is no difference in the one generated in my live production app.

But I still get:

```
Error 400

Error: invalid_request

Missing required parameter: scope
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at your Google App in the Google Developer Console? I'm guessing that you might not have provided an authorized Redirect URI in there for your production app (assuming it is working locally, this is the most likely scenario). Sometimes the errors given by Google are incorrect / ambiguous (I've learned this the hard way).

Answer (score 7):

I take it you are using the Passport Google OAuth, not just the Passport Google (OpenId) module?

If you are using the OAuth passport, the authentication with Google requires an extra scope parameter.

Pass as a string, you must pass 'openid' as the 1st word, eg:
For example, if you wanted per-file access to a user’s Google Drive,

```
openid profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
```

Source(s):

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#scope-param
https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#login-scopes

Comment: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth vs https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google

Comment: Nice answer on here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352975/passport-google-oauth-on-localhost?lq=1

Answer (score -1):

For error message

```
Error 400
Error: invalid_request
Missing required parameter: scope
```

You need to add scopes in your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="scope" value="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo#email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks https://www-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/api/people https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" />
```

Please refer [spring social login](https://github.com/sunilpulugula/SpringSecuritySocialLoginExample) with linkedin,facebook,twitter and google providers example application.

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.* All the more true when repeatedly linking to your own external work, without noting that fact.

Comment: Actually both posts are related with same error message and issue.As I resolved this issue with above statements,so sharing my solution with others.Sure I will not duplicate my posts here after.